# C# TCP/IP Custom IP and Port

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have found the below code on the internet, and I need to allow my users to enter their own IP Address and Port number, as opposed to hard-coded.

I allow my users to enter a IP and Port from two individual text boxes.

```
            try
        {
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting");
            tcpclnt.Connect(syn_ip.Text, 7878);

            Console.WriteLine("Connected");

            //String str=Console.ReadLine();x
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes("data here");
            Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.");

            stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

            byte[] bb = new byte[100];
            int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);

            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));


            tcpclnt.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex.ToString());

        }
```

It will let me send my data over using the above, but I really do need to be able to enter in the port number.

When I do try something like the below, I get the following error: Argument: Cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'.

```
tcpclnt.Connect(syn_ip.Text, syn_port.Text);
```

Thanks for all the help in advance :)
James.

Answer (score 3):

In this code

```
tcpclnt.Connect(syn_ip.Text, syn_port.Text);
```

syn_port.Text is a string type, but an integer is expected.  The simple fix is

```
tcpclnt.Connect(syn_ip.Text, int.Parse(syn_port.Text));
```

This will throw an exception at runtime if anything but an integer is entered.  Instead, consider the more robust solution

```
int port;
bool ok = int.TryParse(syn_port.Text, out port);
if (ok) 
{
    tcpclnt.Connect(syn_ip.Text, port);
}
else // Some error message
```

Note that you should also modify the UI to only allow integers to be entered.  You should also never trust a UI (as a general practice), so also validate that you received an integer in your code that uses the input.

Comment: I always just build int into a `while` loop: `while (!int.TryParse(input, out value)) { /* Read input here */ }`

Comment: @EBrown: Since this is a WinForms app, /* Read Input Here */ is a bit more complicated.  He's probably running this code in response to a UI event (e.g. button click).  He'll need to notify the user that there was a problem and return from the event handler in order for the UI to keep working and collect new input.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the port to an integer value.

```
int port = Int32.Parse(syn_port.Text);
tcpclnt.Connect(syn_ip.Text, port);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tcpclnt.Connect(syn_ip.Text, int.Parse(syn_port.Text));
```

You just need to convert the port `string` to an `int`, as the error suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to convert user input I would recommend [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) considering it could not always be an int.

```
int port;
if (int.TryParse(syn_port.Text, port))
{
   tcpclnt.Connect(syn_ip.Text, port);
}
```